# Math behind Unity3D camera model

Tags: model, camera, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for detailed information regarding the math behind Unity camera model. For example, for a given 3D point what are all the calculations done in background that lead to its positioning within camera space?

I'm aware that, just like OpenGL, Unity has a Model, View and Projection matrix so can I assume the type and order of all the operations shown in this [OpenGL tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/) are pretty much the same?

Comment: I guess. But why do you need this information? What is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I've developed a projection mapping application within Unity3D. I'm trying to match a real world referencial (corner of the wall, for example) with Unity's 3D referencial which is working. However, Problem arises when I try to project 3D points, they do not show up where they're supposed to (they're a little lower than they should). I'm trying to understand Unity's camera model so that I can fix this problem.